Html: Load different image based on rendered image size (not screen/viewport size)
I am trying to load a small on a big image depending on the actual size the image is being rendered (not the viewport size).
If the rendered width is 300px or smaller, I want to load small.jpg which is 600px wide. If the rendered width exceeds 300px, I want to load big.jpg. The closest I got is with the code below. However the breakpoint is around 270px and not 300px and I am having quite some issues understand why that is happening. Is there a way to tell the browser to load the small image if the rendered width is <= 300px?
<picture style="display: block; margin: 9vh auto 2em; max-width: min(32em,70vw);">
  <source 
    srcset="/small.jpg 600w,
            /big.jpg 986w"
    sizes="(max-width: 300px) 300px, (max-width: 600px) 100vw, 1200px">
  <img 
    src="/big.jpg"
    style="max-height: 100%;
           max-width: 100%;
           background-size: cover;
           background-clip: content-box;
           object-fit: contain;
           height: auto;
           width: auto;" />
</picture>


Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>) and include the real jpgs as well.
